# JavaScript on click doesn't work in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

I have a JavaScript which I have to perform on click in PDF.

```
window.open('https://app.box.com/embed/s/fslfd3x8rlrlx5s7crhxyno98tir6cqo', "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=310,width=700,height=500");
```

I have to embed this PDF inside an HTML page. On clicking an image, above javascript should be invoked but nothing happens. How do I do this ?

Comment: please add your onclick function and html @gem_finder_1991

Comment: window.open('https://app.box.com/embed/s/fslfd3x8rlrlx5s7crhxyno98tir6cqo', "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=100,left=310,width=700,height=500")

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                    <embed src = "/div.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0"  height="100%" type='application/pdf'style="border: none;" />
            </div> 

this is html